# Frame skips in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: technical-issues, jetpack-joyride

I have been playing Jetpack Joyride for a while on my iPod, but suddenly one day it started freezing on frames. I have timed it, and it happens on every other second, the game will freeze for a beat and then continue on normally (only for to freeze again in two seconds). You can see how this would quickly get annoying.

I thought closing the app and re-opening it would work, and that this was just some small bug or lag. But it turns out that starting the game fresh with no other apps running in the background did not change anything. Neither did turning the iPod off and turning it back on again. It has been a full week now, and the problem still persists and I have not found any information online relating to it.

Has anyone else experienced this problem before and does anyone have a fix for it?

Comment: What is your iPod model and what ios it has installed?

Comment: Model: A1421, running version 8.3 iOS.

Comment: Have you try to reinstall the game?

Comment: No. Won't it reset my data if I do?

Comment: It depends, if you buck it up on iTunes (properly) then they won't be deleted.

Comment: Not sure if I want to do that (my connection to wi-fi is sparse, and the times I do have it it is sketchy). Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: You shouldn't go and dive so deeply into the problem if it's not necessary. sometimes the most easiest solution is the best. that's why you should exclude the most common problems first.

Comment: It is necessary, though. It is very hard to play the game with freezing frames.

Comment: I strongly recommend contacting Halfbrick Support and have them help fix your issue.

Comment: Okay, I'll try both of those. I guess I'll come back here once I find if re-installing solves the problem or not.